# Current state of reliable execution scheduling

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, governorlimits, schedulebatch

A number of approaches to more reliable scheduling and continuous processing have been used over time on the Salesforce platform, all of them suffering from serious drawbacks. These include:

- **suicidal scheduling**, where a scheduled job enqueues another scheduled job and then aborts itself. Salesforce has been threatening to penalise the approach with no less than 5 minute delay. Job execution is not reliable.
- **chained queueables**, where a queuable calls itself. Salesforce states that the back-off for that will top at around a minute. Job execution is also not reliable. Hard to test in developer orgs.
- **chained batch jobs**, where a batch job calls itself. The newer `BatchApexErrorEvent` also offers a way to handle limit exceptions. Salesforce has a back-off for this job type as well, topping at around 4 minutes. Again, job execution is not reliable.
- **virtual batches**, where a custom iterable class essentially produces a range of numbers, and actual work and querying is done inside batch scopes. Shares similar problems with other job-based approaches.
- **Javascript driven execution**, where `@RemoteAction` methods are used from a browser to drive execution. Users have to keep their browser windows open.
- **API calls**, where an external system is in charge of execution scheduling and calls in to Salesforce to perform work. While plentiful, API calls are limited and a number of platform users have started with this approach.

Are there any novel approaches that would allow precise scheduling and continuous execution with less drawbacks than the ones above?

Comment: I believe it's termed `suicide scheduling`, not `suicidal scheduling`.

Comment: We run scheduled batches in AWS batch processors and push it back to salesforce.

Comment: @AdrianLarson https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/10/new-apex-queueable-interface.html labels it suicidal but the name itself is not important

Comment: ...anything async on SF platform is subject to resource availability and therefore not reliable or precise by any reasonable definition.

Comment: @RedDevil this sounds like a subset of the API calls approach, where “work” is also done externally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my SObjectWorkQueue I am using batch chaining and serialized work records. It’s not a new approach but worked very reliably in the past for me. Not sure if I ever saw this penalty.

https://github.com/rsoesemann/sobject-work-Queue

￼ ￼
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point Javascript driven execution:

**Javascript driven execution, where @RemoteAction methods are used from a browser to drive execution. Users have to keep their browser windows open.**

This is not the case anymore, with the growth of recent technology, you can run windowless browser via command line and write your scripts to run your VF page.

One option would be to use [Headless-Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) and [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), you can log in via JWT and open VF page and start your job.
With the power of batch scripting, shell scripting you can automate this using cron jobs.

I have seen people use this for automated testing UI. Anywho, this can be used to achieve scheduled batch job runs.

This wont' consume API calls, and you decide your own running time as each transaction would be synchronous.

Comment: note that this costs a license if done properly.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman yes it does, but eventually the costs saved in api calls and using a proper Middleware is lot more than a single user licence cost